# is CNContactStoreDidChange is working ? I'm not able to get callback when contacts are changed

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code, I am registering notification in viewDidLoadwithoptins in appDelegate.

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                           self, selector: #selector(contactStoreDidChange), name: .CNContactStoreDidChange, object: nil)
```

and here is my function

```
 @objc func contactStoreDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {


           print("Contacts Changed")
           UserDefaults.standard.set("Log Changed \(Date())", forKey: "contact")
               }
```

I am not getting any notifications. I have tried with real device and simulator.

Comment: did it worked for you?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have observed, this notification only gets called when we use the `CNContactStore` atleast once in our app.
So, go to your Screen where your contacts are fetched atleast once.

So basically

```
let store = CNContactStore()

store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (status, error) in
}
```

The above snippet should be executed once.
Then go to the Contacts app by making your app go to the background, make a change in a contact, and come back to your app. You will see this notification gets fired.

Also make sure to add the observer in some class which exists the whole time, like `AppDelegate`.